# Find the N adjactent unit squares that contain the most 2D points

Tags: algorithms

So, I have a set of 2D points with real valued positions.
I want to find a set of N adjacent unit squares that contains the most points possible.
If it's easier, this could be a set of N adjacent (or overlapping) disks.

Any idea how I could do that?
Thank you :)

Comment: What do you call adjacent ?

Comment: Can the set be a long snake?

Comment: Do the unit squares also have unit co-ordinates?

Comment: @YvesDaoust, the squares need to touch. They could be overlapping, or only have a corner touching

Thank you!

Comment: @RayButterworth Absolutely

Thank you!

Comment: @RobertLongson Not necessarily, but if that helps, why not?
Thank you!

Comment: @AdrienNivaggioli: if the coordinates are constrained to be "unit" (presumably integer), that makes a different problem.

Comment: @YvesDaoust To be honest, I'm trying to find the best I can. If the answer is: No good algorithm will run in acceptable time with real values coordinates (for both points and squares), but there is an approximation for integer coordinates, that would be great.
But indeed, it would be better if the coordinates are not constrained.

Comment: Please don't add clarifications in the comments.  Instead, plase [edit] the question so all information is contained in the question, and so it reads well for people who encounter it for the first time (don't use 'edit:').  Then, flag comments as no longer needed.